# How is it possible for two identical Docker images to have different packages installed?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, coreos

## Initial Post

I have the same docker image running on two different CoreOS servers. (They're in a Kubernetes cluster, but I think that is irrelevant to the current problem.)

They both are running image hash `01e95e0a93af`. They both should have curl. One does not. This seems... impossible.

*Good Server*

```
core@ip-10-0-0-61 ~ $ docker pull gcr.io/surveyadmin-001/wolfgang:commit_e78e07eb6ce5727af6ffeb4ca3e903907e3ab83a
Digest: sha256:5d8bf456ad2d08ce3cd15f05b62fddc07fda3955267ee0d3ef73ee1a96b98e68
[cut]
Status: Image is up to date for gcr.io/surveyadmin-001/wolfgang:commit_e78e07eb6ce5727af6ffeb4ca3e903907e3ab83a

core@ip-10-0-0-61 ~ $ docker run -it --rm gcr.io/surveyadmin-001/wolfgang:commit_e78e07eb6ce5727af6ffeb4ca3e903907e3ab83a /bin/bash
root@d29cb8783830:/app/bundle# curl
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
root@d29cb8783830:/app/bundle#
```

*Bad Server*

```
core@ip-10-0-0-212 ~ $ docker pull gcr.io/surveyadmin-001/wolfgang:commit_e78e07eb6ce5727af6ffeb4ca3e903907e3ab83a
[cut]
Digest: sha256:5d8bf456ad2d08ce3cd15f05b62fddc07fda3955267ee0d3ef73ee1a96b98e68
Status: Image is up to date for gcr.io/surveyadmin-001/wolfgang:commit_e78e07eb6ce5727af6ffeb4ca3e903907e3ab83a

core@ip-10-0-0-212 ~ $ docker run -it --rm gcr.io/surveyadmin-001/wolfgang:commit_e78e07eb6ce5727af6ffeb4ca3e903907e3ab83a /bin/bash
root@fe6a536393f8:/app/bundle# curl
bash: curl: command not found
root@fe6a536393f8:/app/bundle#
```

[Full logs available on this gist](https://gist.github.com/iameli/72506721b70dcba6d5b2). I took the bad server out of our production cluster but still have it running if anyone wants me to do any other research.

## Added 2015-12-04

I've run `docker tag gcr.io/surveyadmin-001/wolfgang:commit_e78e07eb6ce5727af6ffeb4ca3e903907e3ab83a weird-image` on both servers to make everything more readable.

### which curl

> Can you do a which curl in the first component to check where it finds its curl? And see if that file exists in the second component. – VonC

Seems to not exist at all on the bad server.

*Good Server*

```
core@ip-10-0-0-61 ~ $ docker run -it --rm weird-image /bin/bash 
root@529b8f20a610:/app/bundle# which curl
/usr/bin/curl
```

*Bad Server*

```
core@ip-10-0-0-212 ~ $ docker run -it --rm weird-image /bin/bash 
root@ff98c850dbaa:/app/bundle# ls /usr/bin/curl
ls: cannot access /usr/bin/curl: No such file or directory
root@ff98c850dbaa:/app/bundle#
```

### alias docker

> Any chance you have set up an alias on the bad box? Run alias docker to check – morloch

Nope.

*Good Server*

```
core@ip-10-0-0-61 ~ $ alias docker
-bash: alias: docker: not found
```

*Bad Server*

```
core@ip-10-0-0-212 ~ $ alias docker
-bash: alias: docker: not found
```

### time

More weirdness: it takes a lot longer to run the container on the bad server.

*Good Server*

```
core@ip-10-0-0-61 ~ $ time docker run weird-image echo "Done"
Done

real  0m0.422s
user  0m0.015s
sys 0m0.015s
```

*Bad Server*

```
core@ip-10-0-0-212 ~ $ time docker run weird-image echo "Done"
Done

real  0m4.602s
user  0m0.010s
sys 0m0.010s
```

Comment: Can you do a `which curl` in the first component to check where it finds its `curl`? And see if that file exists in the second component.

Comment: Any chance you have set up an alias on the bad box? Run `alias docker` to check

Comment: Updated with responses to both. No luck so far.

Comment: I would try to compare the `docker history` of the images on both servers, to see if there is any difference. Also the output of `dpkg -l` (assuming debian/ubuntu) or  the equivalent to list all installed packages.

Comment: @dnephin I have access to the server; I'll respond. `docker history` is identical for the image on both servers (see [full logs](https://gist.github.com/iameli/72506721b70dcba6d5b2)). There's no `dpkg`, but (as mentioned in the question), the normal container boots with `curl`, the weird container without. Looks like `/usr/bin` in a weird container has 240 files, but 247 files in the normal container.

Comment: maybe a stupid suggestion, but when you're pulling, you get the message that the image is up-to-date, which to me means it is not being pulled. Have you tried deleting the local image and pulling again?

Comment: Do you have AppArmor or similar configured differently on the servers? what is the output of `docker info` and `docker version` for both server? Is the output of `docker inspect <container>` different (apart from e.g. hostname or IPAddress) for both servers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen lots of cases where Docker images on-disk get random bits of corruption (causing weird inconsistencies like the one you describe here), and deleting and re-pulling the image "fixes" the problem.

To test this, you'll want to make sure you not only `docker rmi gcr.io/surveyadmin-001/wolfgang:commit_e78e07eb6ce5727af6ffeb4ca3e903907e3ab83a` (which will minimally output `Untagged: gcr.io/surveyadmin-001/wolfgang:commit_e78e07eb6ce5727af6ffeb4ca3e903907e3ab83a`), but also delete the individual layers (and any other tags they may have) so that they're forced to be re-pulled.

Comment: Accepted 'cause that certainly has to be what's going on here. Would love it if there were more tools for diagnosing such a thing though.

Comment: "lots of cases"! This is terrifying.